# Grails 2.4.3 App Deployment Error on Tomcat

Tags: grails, tomcat7, grails-2.4

Trying to deploy a Grails 2.4.3 application to Tomcat 7.55

keep getting this error:

```
LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1247)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1898)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jline.console.completer.CompletionHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
```

Here is the BuildConfig:

I have no problems running it on my local machine. Even with "grails prod run-war". I'm going to try to take out dependencies to see if any are the problem. Not sure where jLine is coming from though. From searching around, I've found that Jasper Reports uses jLine (which I used to have installed, but don't anymore). I haven't found any of the other libs that use it though. Is there anything in Tomcat that would use it?

```
    grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" 

    grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
        // inherit Grails' default dependencies
        inherits("global") {
            // uncomment to disable ehcache
            // excludes 'ehcache'
        }
        log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
        checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve

        repositories {
            inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins
            grailsPlugins()
            grailsHome()
            grailsCentral()
            mavenCentral()
            mavenLocal()
            mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/"

        }
        dependencies {
            runtime 'org.drools:drools-core:5.6.0.Final'
            runtime 'org.drools:drools-compiler:5.6.0.Final'
            test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.4"
        }

        plugins {
            runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
            runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.5"
            runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
            compile ":cache-headers:1.1.7"
            compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
        compile ":rendering:1.0.0"
            compile ":quartz2:2.1.6.2"
            compile ":joda-time:1.5"
            compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.6"
            compile ":browser-detection:0.4.3"
            compile ":cache:1.1.7"
            compile ":grails-melody:1.52.0"

            compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"


            build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        }
    }
```

Comment: Add `BuildConfig` to the question? Do you use JRebel?

Comment: No, not using JRebel. This is on a local test machine with clean tomcat installs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was caused by the application.properties file. I was loading the application.properties from the lib directory in Tomcat and it was not formatted correctly for a deployed war file.